# New feature added for newer version but not for older version

Tags: ios, compatibility, ios10

If we use an API for adding a feature, which is compatible only in iOS10 (For example Siri API), should I change my app compatibility to iOS10 or do I have a choice to inform the end user that, this feature is available only in iOS 10, but the app works normally in prior version.

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build against the iOS 10 SDK, set your deployment target to iOS 9, then use some Swift like this:

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    // use SFSpeechRecognizer
} else {
    // show message to user
}
```

Clearly Apple won't be terribly happy with you in app review if it's a really critical feature that isn't available, but as long as it's not central to the app's purpose and you're clear with the user, I think the above is the best solution.

I wrote a [tutorial on Swift availability checking](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking) that you might find useful.